# Magento Cloud Docker Can't get version of elasticsearch: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: elasticsearch

Tags: development, docker, magento2-cloud

I want to set up a Local Development Environment with Docker but I have no experience with Docker.
I ran `./bin/magento-docker ece-deploy`and get the error: `ERROR: [132] Can't get version of elasticsearch: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: elasticsearch`.
Can anyone help me please with this issue?
This a part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
elasticsearch:
    hostname: elasticsearch.magento2.docker
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-elasticsearch:7.7-1.2.3'
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster,
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - elasticsearch.magento2.docker
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the ElasticSearch container kept exiting during the deployment. This was solved by giving more memory to docker.